# Android Imageview from URL in Fragment not displaying

Tags: android, imageview, fragment

Exactly what the title says. I'm trying to display an imageView from a URl in a fragment, but nothing shows up. Android doesn't crash, and the layout is just empty.
I have internet permissions enabled in my manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Java code here

```
public class InboxFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
  Bundle savedInstanceState) {

View V = inflater.inflate(R.layout.inbox_frag_layout, container, false);
ImageView image = (ImageView)V.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
Drawable drw =LoadImageFromWebOperations("http://i.imgur.com/Svphn.jpg");
image.setImageDrawable(drw);

return V;

}

private Drawable LoadImageFromWebOperations(String strPhotoUrl) {
try {
  InputStream is = (InputStream) new URL(strPhotoUrl).getContent();
  Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");
  return d; 
}catch (Exception e) { 
  System.out.println("Exc="+e); 
  return null;
}

}
}
```

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width = "wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    >
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imgView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Update: fixed it by using webview instead.

Answer (score 1):

I have suspected the problem but dont know the solution but sill want to share. Every network call takes time to execute. This time is always greater then the CPU speed of executing single line of code statement. So when you call LoadImageFromWebOperations() function dont expect that it will get the drawable from net in real time. As soon as LoadImageFromWebOperations() function execute and return the response onCreateView() function will already finish its execution and return the view without setting image on imageView.

The possible solution can be:
Return the view without setting the image on it. And wait for image downloaded from net once it downloaded then get current view of the fragment(which i dont know how) and set image on it.

I am expecting some one to give solution that how to get current view of a fragment.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code get the bitmap from url:::

```
URL newurl = new URL(streamURL); 
HttpGet httpRequest = null;
try  {
    httpRequest = new HttpGet(newurl.toURI());
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpRequest);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(entity);
InputStream instream = bufHttpEntity.getContent();
Bitmap mIcon_val = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(instream);
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your life easier use the AQuery Library at http://code.google.com/p/android-query/.

Using the library will enable you to set an imageview from a URL in a single line:

```
aq.id(R.id.image1).image("http://www.vikispot.com/z/images/vikispot/android-w.png");
```

I would suggest this as it handles the downloading for you without any extra code. It also does it asynchronously meaning your UI thread won't get blocked meaning no slowdown to the user.